# Function Parameter Undefined - Javascript

Tags: javascript, function

I am trying to pass in a variable as a parameter to a function but its saying its undefined.

I'm thinking it may be something to do with it being asynchronous or out of scope but they function can only ever be called after the data is populated.

I first declare the variable as global.

The function oneCall is also out of scope, I call the function from another JS file within a Jquery function for onclick - the div is loaded in after the webpage so this is why i used this method.

I had to put the function out of scope of the socket functions so it could be accessed by the html.

The variable being assigned in index.js:

```
var itemIdArray = []
var itemId = 0

io.of('/main').on('connection', function (socket) {

socket.on('chat message', function (msg) {
    //Add if statement to check if message is empty
    io.of('/main').to(socket.id).emit('chat message', msg);
    var message = msg
    logmsg = {
        "user": socket.id,
        msg
    }
    const request = {
        session: sessionPath,
        queryInput: {
            text: {
                text: message,
                languageCode: languageCode,
            },
        },
    };
    // Dialogflow logic
    sessionClient
        .detectIntent(request)
        .then(responses => {
            console.log('Detected intent');
            result = responses[0].queryResult;
            response = result.fulfillmentText;
            responseHappened = true;

            var responseOrderByNum = response.includes('itemId');
            if (responseOrderByNum) {
                var jsonObj = JSON.parse(response)      
                itemIdArray = jsonObj.itemId

            }
```

My function with the parameter:

```
function oneCall(itemId, itemIdArray) {
console.log('itemIdArray' + itemIdArray)
itemId = itemIdArray[0];
```

}

Calling the function in the other JS file:

```
            $('#item1Wrapper').on('click', function () {
                oneCall();
            });
```

Comment: Can you please show where you are **invoking** the `oneCall` function? Since it's out of scope and it has a **parameter** named as `itemIdArray`, it will look for the **local** one (the function's argument). Please show the entire code so that we can better help you.

Comment: Oh, sure, sorry! I'll do it now.

Comment: It's done, I added it.

Comment: I believe you have to call oneCall method after response of sessionClient. or you have to make your call synchronous. because on click of  $('#item1Wrapper'), your oneCall method will fire before getting response from sessionClient

Comment: No mano, My function can only be called after the response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its undefined because you havent passed any parameters into the function,

```
function oneCall(itemId, itemIdArray) {
  console.log('itemIdArray' + itemIdArray)
  itemId = itemIdArray[0];
}
```

try calling the function like,

```
$('#item1Wrapper').on('click', function () {
    console.log(itemId, itemIdArray);//make sure these variables have some values.
    oneCall(itemId, itemIdArray);
});
```

Even though the variables are global, if used inside a function with parameters having same names, those variables will be identified as local variables which came as parameters. You can try changing the parameter names too.

Comment: Okay but if when the function is called the variables are also mentioned, then it uses the global scope?

Comment: It still returns as undefined

Comment: No, if you use a global variable and a local variable with same name, the local variable is accessed. If you passed the global variable as a parameter in function call, its value will be passed to the function which can be accessed inside the function. But if you are still getting undefined make sure the variable you passed has a value and its not undefined. Do a console.log before the function call. `console.log(itemId, itemIdArray);oneCall(itemId, itemIdArray);`

Comment: The console.log won't work because the the itemIdArray is assigned data after a GET request, but the GET request always happens before the function is called?

Answer (score 0):

```js
var itemIdArray = []
var itemId = 0

function badCall(itemId, itemIdArray) {
  console.log('itemIdArray' + itemIdArray)
  itemId = itemIdArray[0];
}

function betterCall() {
  console.log('itemIdArray' + itemIdArray)
  itemId = itemIdArray[0];
}

//badCall();

itemIdArray = [1,2,3];

//badCall();

betterCall();

console.log( itemId );
```

The parameters are not passed when you call the function. `oneCall();` They are global, so can you just use them in the function without passing them in as arguments?

```
function oneCall() {
    console.log('itemIdArray' + itemIdArray)
    itemId = itemIdArray[0];
}
```

Comment: So if I set them as parameters they set themselves empty again?

Comment: Still returned as undefined

Comment: I added a snippet so you can see that if the signature of the function has arguments, you must pass parameters when you call it. If you call `badCall` in here it will be undefined. Regardless, I suspect your itemIdArray is not populated when you make the call. Can you provide a snippet that mimics the behavior?